# Typing in Tor Browser opens an advertising tab

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have the Tor Browser Bundle on Linux. When I start to type in a
text box in the browser I often get shifted immediately to a
new tab with some advertising. It doesn't happen every time, and
in particular if I kill the advertising tab and go back to the
original tab, I can type without hindrance.

Any idea whats causing this?

Answer (score 3):

Did you check that you have a legitimate version of Tor? (Using the Checksums provided etc) Sounds like either your browser was compromised or you installed a faulty add on.